# Is there sth like `eval` in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, eval

Can I evaluate cypher code from a string in Neo4j? I think about something like `eval` function in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be helped by the [`apoc` library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) with a rich set of tools to [execute the `cypher`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#cypher-execution) from the string:

```
call db.labels() yield label
call apoc.cypher.run("match (:`"+label+"`) return count(*) as count", null) yield value
return label, value.count as count
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it's important to add that `run` method is read-only, for writing we should use `apoc.cypher.doIt` (that's described in the linked docs, but it took me a while to understand why my code doesn't work).