# How to use wildcard in relationship name in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this theoretical graph structure:

```
(:Car)<-[:LIKES_C]-(:Person)-[:LIKES_B]->(:Bike)
```

`Person` also has other relationships not containing a word *LIKES*, say `(:Person)-[:LOVES]-(:Person)`

I'd like to write a cypher query which will yield all nodes connected to a `Person` with a relation, which name starts with *LIKES*.

Also I cannot change relation names to `LIKES` because there are lots of nodes with label `Bike` and `Car` and according to [this post](https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-genericvague-relationship-names/) Neo4j will be inefficient in a query like:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(:Car)
```

It will search through both `Cars` and `Bikes` and *then* filter for `Cars` effectively increasing execution time.

Is there an efficient way to query for `LIKES*` relationship?

Comment: If you plan/expect to execute both the generic and specific queries often, I'm wondering if just adding the generic `:LIKES` relationship in addition to the specific `:LIKES_*` relationships is the way to go.  Won't a graph model aligned with the queries be more efficient, in general?

Comment: Yeah it seems a good solution too. What I would lose though is a little bit of time and space for creating this additional relations and much of `db.schema` clarity...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jakub! 
There is way to match set of relationship types:

```
match (p:Person)-[:LIKES_C|LIKES_B]->(carOrBike)
```

In that case you will be able to traverse both `:LIKES_C` and `:LIKES_B` relationships from `:Person` node.

One could also use `UNWIND` with a list of relationship names in combination with `apoc.cypher.run` (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433173/is-there-sth-like-eval-in-neo4j)) to query for multiple relations at once.

Comment: Isn't it `[:LIKES_C|:LIKES_B]`? [`Neo4j Cypher Manual: MATCH on multiple relationship types`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/index.html#match-on-multiple-rel-types)

Comment: as i have tested on 3.5.3 version - working both ways. but if we refer to docs https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/#match-on-multiple-rel-types your variant is correct

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, however I'm planning to have multiple `LIKE*` relations, so I'm looking for a more generic way of doing it. I assume though that it would require creating the query dynamically... or could I use `UNWIND` for relation names?

Comment: about unwind, you can try apoc.cypher.run https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433173/is-there-sth-like-eval-in-neo4j